# Getting tighter spacing on Github markdown with syntax highlighted blocks

Tags: github, markdown, github-pages

I've noticed that if I use language-specific syntax highlighting on Github (e.g. Ruby)

[image: ruby example block]

There's a lot of space between code block and preceding text.
However, when using the plain shell syntax block, the spacing is tighter:

[image]

Just wondering if anyone has found a way to get the spacing tighter when using language-specific syntax highlighting.

Answer (score 0):

For your own pages, you might try and fiddle with different css as in " [jasonm23 / markdown-css-themes](https://github.com/jasonm23/markdown-css-themes)".

See this [example page](http://jasonm23.github.io/markdown-css-themes/markdown-alt.html).